# bash: swap two commands syntactically, but keep the same execution order

Tags: bash, pipe

Consider chain of commands:

```
cmd1 | cmd1 | cmd2
```

Question: how to swap `cmd1` and `cmd2` syntactically (so that `cmd1` will be placed after `cmd2`, at the end of the chain), but keep the original execution order (so that `cmd1` is executed before `cmd2`)?

Comment: Homework? or do you have a goal?

Comment: why...........?

Comment: and also, that's a pipeline, the commands in it are executed _simultaneously_, not one before another.

Comment: I thought pipelines executed commands in sequence

Comment: In some cases commands within a pipe sequence can be swapped and the net result will be the same but there are cases when it will just not work at all.

Comment: The data flows through all the processes in the order the commands are written (they each get to modify the data on the way through). But the data passes down the line in a continuous stream. It does not all wait for cmd1 to finish before anything else happens.

Comment: Could you replace `cmd1` and `cmd2` in your pipeline with some real commands? That would make it easier to talk about it, about what's possible and about what's happening behind the scenes.

Comment: `cmd1` appears two times. Which one do you want to swap with `cmd2`? Both?

Comment: @Akuseru, the data passes through the pipeline in sequence, but in general, the processes execute simultaneously. Consider the common case of `ps uax |grep whatever`, where the output of the pipeline can contain a line for the `grep` process too. That line is printed by `ps` when it looks for the processes running at the moment it is running.

Comment: @ilkkachu oh, that makes sense now! thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd1 | cmd1 | cmd2
```

can be substituted with:

```
cmd1 | cmd2 < <(cmd1)
```

`<(cmd1)` changes  output of `cmd1` into file descriptor, and previous `<` feeds it to `cmd2` in pipe-like manner.

You cannot simply change order of commands retaining pipe operator (`|`) because it chains inputs and outputs of commands and changing order of commands changes meaning of entire command.

Comment: in your substitute command, `cmd2` does read from stdin. You're mixing that up with `cmd2 <(cmd1)` where it has to open the process substitution filename itself.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Thanks for pointing that out. I've forgot that `< <()` is not the same as  `<()`. I am not using it very often. Answer has been changed.

Comment: yep, and it's easy to miss the other `<` when eyeballing the command line... If you wanted to, I think you could also invert the whole pipeline as `doo < <(bar < <(foo))`, instead of just flipping the last two commands. It gets increasingly ugly, but at least the data flow is just in one direction

Comment: Also note that _the execution order_ in the original pipeline is "concurrent" (all parts are executed at once), whereas in the answer, `cmd2` starts after `cmd1` in the process substitution.  Therefore, the execution order is not preserved.